# How to remove Blank space from the string?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I have a table created in oracle with field Org varchar2

```
create table new ( org varchar2(10));
```

insert three records

```
insert into new values ('127') ;
insert into new values ('128') ;
insert into new values ('129') ;
```

Run this sql with parameter : 127, 128,129, you will get 127,129 but not 128 because there is blank space before 128, Is there any way I can get rid of Blank space in this sql and get output 127,128,129 .

```
 SELECT org FROM new WHERE org IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL2(:p_org_code,:p_org_code,org),
       '[^,]+',
       1,
       LEVEL)
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL2(:p_org_code,:p_org_code,org),
       '[^,]+',
       1,
       LEVEL)
IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Will RTRIM() and LTRIM() functions do the job?

Comment: I don't understand, where is the white space? I can't see any

Comment: do string trimming before inserting values. see http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php

Comment: added `oracle` tag based on the usage of `varchar2` and `connect by` in the question

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove leading whitespace, use the `ltrim()` function. If you want to remove trailing whitespace, use the `rtrim()` function. If you want to remove both leading and trailing whitespace, nest them: `ltrim(rtrim(s))`.

One might note that using these functions with a single argument, e.g., `ltrim( some_string_expression )`, these functions remove **only** leading/trailing *spaces* (0x20, ASCII SP).

Oracle's PL/SQL has an alternative form: `[lr]trim( str_to_trim , str_containing_trim_chars )` where the second string defines the set of characters to be trimmed. The "usual" definition of whitespace is

- `HT`, horizontal tab, (0x09, dec 9)
- `LF`, line feed, (0x0A, dec 10)
- `VT`, vertical tab, (0x0B, dec 11)
- `FF`, form feed, (0x0C, dec 12)
- `CR`, carriage return, (0x0D, dec 13)
- `SP`, space (0x20, dec 32)

so to trim those, you'd say something like:

```
rtrim(ltrim( source_string ,
  chr(9)+chr(10)+char(11)+char(12),+char(13)+char(32) ) ,
  chr(9)+chr(10)+char(11)+char(12),+char(13)+char(32) )
```

If you want to remove *all* whitespace from a string, you can use PL/SQL's `translate()` function, Something like

```
translate(
  source_string ,
  chr(9)+chr(10)+char(11)+char(12),+char(13)+char(32) , -- whitespace chars
  ''                                                    -- replacement chars
  )
```

removes all whitespace from the source string.

You can also use PL/SQL's regular expressions:

- `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the string
- `$` anchors the match at the end of the string
- `[:space:]` matches a single whitespace character.

You can remove leading/trailing whitespace like this:

```
regex_replace( source, '(^[:space]+)|([:space:]+$)' , '' )
```

You can collapse embedded whitespace sequences into a single space character like this:

```
regex_replace( source , '[:space:]+' , ' ' )
```

and finally, you can "normalize" a string, by removing leading/trailing whitespace and replacing all embedded sequences of 1 or more whitespace characters with a single space character like this:

```
ltrim(rtrim(regex_replace( source , '[:space:]+' , ' ' )))
```

There is, as they say, more than one way to do it.

Comment: Instead of nesting `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` you can use the `TRIM` function which serves the same purpose. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis: my PL/SQL is a bit rusty B^) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
RTRIM(LTRIM('128 '))
```

The output will be '128'

Comment: you can use just the `trim` function, it excludes white spaces from around the value.

Answer (score 0):

If  you ask us how to get rid of white spaces around the value then:

```
with t as (
  select '123    ' id from dual union all
  select '    124' id from dual union all
  select '  125   ' id from dual 
)
select *
  from t
 where trim(id) in (123, 124, 125)

ID
---
123
124
125
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  WHERE ORG LIKE '%128%';
```

Share and enjoy.